# yii framework form-attributes-not-saved in database

Tags: yii

I'm trying to save the data from a form. The yii framework form attributes is not being saved in the database.

Here is my code for the controller:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller {

  public function actionSave() {
    if (isset($_POST['Patients'])) {
        $patients = new Patients;
        $patients->name = $_POST['Patients']['name'];
        $patients->mobile = $_POST['Patients']['mobile'];
        $patients->email = $_POST['Patients']['email'];
        $patients->password = $_POST['Patients']['password'];
        $patients->dob = $_POST['Patients']['dob'];
        $patients->weight = $_POST['Patients']['weight'];
        $patients->height = $_POST['Patients']['height'];
        $patients->activation_date = '0000-00-00';
        $patients->credit = 0;
        $patients->archive = 0;
        $patients->balance = 0;
        $patients->first_login = 0;
        $patients->guide_status = 0;
        $patients->passcode = '';
    }

    //echo $patients->save_personal_data();

    $valid = $patients->validate();
    if ($valid) {
        $patients->save();
    } else {
        var_dump($patients->getErrors());
    }
       if ($patients->save()) {
           echo 'saved';
       }  else {

                       var_dump($patients->getErrors());
       }
}
```

It isn't saving in the database. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: var_dump($patients->getErrors());   what's show ?

Comment: it should save because it prints save but nothing in the database

Comment: I have posted an asnwer  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't save in the DB. Typically the issue is related to the validation rules.

Just for debugging, try using save(false)

```
//$valid = $patients->validate();
$patients->save(false);
```

If the model is saved, then check selectively for rules applied to the model.